# Need to access user's contact book for alexa skill

Tags: javascript, api, twilio, alexa-skills-kit

I am building an Alexa skill and need to access user's contact book from their phone.
The skill would then be able to send data it has to intended phone number from contact list.
I am using twilio for the purpose of messaging.
How to access contact list of user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You cannot access a users contacts on their device via the Alexa app.

You would either need to build your own native application that your user would need to install in order to access their contacts or make a web application for the user to enter their contacts into that you can then use within the skill.

Comment: Thank you. Alternatively ,can I get access to user's contact on his google account if he agrees to login with google id? If yes, Please let me know of resources of help.

Comment: Sure, if you build an app that requires user login via Google then you can ask for the permissions to read their contacts. I'd get started with the Google documentation on that API here: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/